# Anyway to select both recent posts and recent threads

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am using LINQ and chain this command into a model.

```
model.LatestPosts = db.TPGForums.SelectMany(m => m.TPGForumTopics)
                                .SelectMany(m => m.TPGForumPosts)
                                .SelectMany(m => m.TPGForumThreads)
                                .OrderByDescending(m => m.dateCreated)
                                .Take(5);
```

This however only brings me back the Threads.  I would need the last 5 most recent items in the `TPGForumPosts` and the `TPGForumThreads`.  How would I return the most recent 5 posts/threads instead of just the most recent threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the `SelectMany` calls, rather than chaining them:

```
var query = db.TPGForums
    .SelectMany(forum => forum.TPGForumTopics
        .SelectMany(topic => topic.TPGForumPosts
            .SelectMany(post => post.TPGForumThreads
                .Select(thread => new { forum, topic, post, thread }))))
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.thread.dateCreated)
    .Take(5);
```

Comment: What should I make my model be for this to work?  The model is currently TPGForumThreads but that no longer accepts this nested input.

Comment: @JamesWilson You can select back out what you want after ordering/taking the items.  If what you want is forums, select out the forums from the anonymous object.